# how to limit right click on selected listview item only or an item rather than empty spaces?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

the right click in listview item is working but it work on every space in the listview, wether it is on item or empty spaces. i want to limit only to selected item.

i tried to use the `listview1.HitTest` but it is not working. still the right click is all the listveiw.

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var loc = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);

            if (loc.Item != null && contextMenuStrip1.Items.Count == 0)
            {

                contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("TEST1");
                contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("TEST2");

            }              

        }
```

Comment: Do you want the context menu to not appear in this case?

Comment: @okrumnow, yes i dont want the context menu to appear in empty areas. just the selected selected or where there is an item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may cancel the `ContextMenuStrip.Opening` event in case the HitTest shows that the mouse is not over an item.

You don't have the mouse position from the event args here, so you have to get it from `Control.MousePosition`

```
public void ContextMenuOpening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {

  Point mousePosition = myListView.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
  ListViewHitTestInfo hit = myListView.HitTest(mousePosition);

  e.Cancel = hit.Item == null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also still do the test inside `listView1_mouseDown()`; I did it this way and it's working fine, thus avoiding having to mess with `ContextMenuOpening` and `Control.MousePosition`. The only difference is that I declared `lvhti`as of `ListViewHitTestInfo` instead of `var`:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{
  ListViewHitTestInfo lvhti = this.listView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y); // or e.Location
  if (lvhti.Item != null){
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(this.listView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
  }              
}
```